# Instant app in development track not served

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have released an **instant app** in both **production** and ***development tracks***. For some reason, I need to stop serving production instant app, So I stopped serving instant app availability in play store.

However, I still want to serve the instant app via development track (*via closed test*).

***My question is, Is instant app uploaded in development track served when instant app availability is stopped?***

I uploaded an instant app in development channel and it's been 2 days I don't see development instant app working at all.

Answer (score 2):

The Stop Serving feature affects all tracks equally. What you can do is set Mobile Holdback on your release track. Set it to 1.00. Then turn serving back on. Make sure dev track has a higher version code than prod, or you still won't get anything.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I don't see anything called Mobile Holdback on release track. Where exactly do I find it?

Comment: Ah, I found it, it's just under the settings on manage release page.

Comment: Adding to the above shared details, you can also refer to section _"Direct users to the mobile web"_ at this link:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861